# Custom Element in MonoTouch.Dialog: StyledMultilineElement top aligned, with UIWebView

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Would like to ask some advice on how to approach custom `Element` design.

My design calls for a `UITableViewCell` which contains the usual text label, detail text label and  custom AccessoryView you'd find in a `StyledMultilineElement`. In addition to this, I'd like to display a `UIWebView` below the DetailTextLabel.

Ideally, the content of the `UIWebView` will slide in and out as the cell is tapped.

It's simple enough to extend `StyledMultilineElement`, but, by default, `StyledMultineElement` vertically center aligns the `TextLabel` and `DetailTextLabel`. By extending `IElementSizing` and overriding `GetHeight`, I can increase the cell size, but labels are centered. Is there a simple way to align them to the top of the cell or will it be necessary to do the layout manually (i.e. in `LayoutSubviews`)?

It is possible to add a custom view, such as `UIWebView`, to a StyledMultilineElement, or would it be advisable to do a completely custom layout?

Comment: Made some progress on this, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431208

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I could find was the keep the `Text` and `DetailText` in a `StyledMultiLineElement`, and use a separate cell to display the rest of the content.