# Display UIWebView in custom MonoTouch.Dialog Element

Tags: uiwebview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Working on a way to display HTML and RTF content in a custom `Element` in `MonoTouch.Dialog`. To get started, I created a new class based on the `UIViewElement` implementation, with the intention of displaying a `UIWebView` in a cell ([see UIViewElement code here](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs)).

The custom element works, but the contents of the `UIWebView` is never displayed. Once the text of the `UIWebView` is loaded, I try to resize it using `UIWebView.SizeThatFits`. This function always return 0s, even though the width given to it (from the actual `UITableViewCell` it is displayed in) is non-zero.

Is it sufficient to add the `UIWebView` to the `UITableViewCell` using this code:

```
cell.ContentView.AddSubview (webView);
```

The `UIWebView` never returns a non-zero height, so the actual cell is never displayed. Even if I override the height calculation and return a static height (such as `100f`), the `UIWebView` is still not displayed.

The element's complete code:

```
public class RBHTMLRow : Element, IElementSizing
{
    public enum CellFlags {Transparent = 1,DisableSelection = 2}
    public CellFlags Flags;
    private UIWebView webView = null;
    private UITableViewCell current_cell;
    NSString key;

    private void ResizeWebView ()
    {
        if (current_cell != null)
        {
            RectangleF frame = webView.Frame;
            SizeF fittingSize = webView.SizeThatFits(new SizeF(current_cell.Frame.Width, 1f));
            frame.Size = fittingSize;
            webView.Frame = frame;
        }
    }

    private void InitWebView(bool isRTF, string content )
    {
        webView = new UIWebView();
        webView.LoadHtmlString ( content, new NSUrl(""));
        webView.LoadFinished += delegate {
            ResizeWebView();
        } ;
    }

    public RBHTMLRow (bool isRTF, String content, String caption) : base (caption)
    {
        key = new NSString("rbhtml_row");
        InitWebView(isRTF, content);
    }

    protected override NSString CellKey {
    get {
        return key;
    }
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell (CellKey);
        if (cell == null){
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellKey);
            if ((Flags & CellFlags.Transparent) != 0){
                cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
                cell.BackgroundView = new UIView (RectangleF.Empty) { 
                    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear 
                } ;
            }

            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
            cell.ContentView.AddSubview (webView);
        }  
        current_cell = cell;
        ResizeWebView();
        return cell;
    }

public float GetHeight (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath){
    return webView.Bounds.Height;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just `cell.AddSubview()`?

Comment: So what `Frame` does the WebView end up with?

Comment: Ok, that looks like it's part of the problem. the `SizeThatFits` returns a `0f` height, which explains why nothing is displayed - the UIWebView frame has a height of 0f. Any idea why `SizeThatFits` does not come back with valid dimensions?

Comment: You have to declare a width/height for a webview.  It doesn't auto-size based on the HTML it loads or anything.

Comment: Did you ever suss this one out?

Comment: No... ended up restructuring the design somewhat to avoid putting HTML in the cells. The webview's `sizeThatFits` methhod may give you a more accurate height of the content. If memory serves, the issue I experience was related to getting that height when the view was originally rendered. At that time, the content had not been loaded in the view and always returned a height of 0. A few people asked about this same issue in different places, but no-one had a working solution.

Comment: Someone also suggested using a `NSAttributedString`, which shows promise, but I never tried it.