# How to display HTML string with MonoTouch Dialog?

Tags: uiwebview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I need a way to display a string with HTML tags within MonoTouch.Dialog element.
If I understand right the build in HTMLElement is only for load external data to display.

So I asked google for and found this thread here [display-uiwebview-in-custom-monotouch-dialog-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431208/display-uiwebview-in-custom-monotouch-dialog-element) but it seems that now solution was found also with some other search results I found ...

Maybe somebody knows if a solution for is still available or if not does somebody know a library to convert the HTML tags from the string that it will get a nice look in standard elements ...?

Thanks

Andre

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UIWebView and add the text there, and then use the UIViewElement to show that.

But this is a little on the heavy side.

Perhaps you should consider using NSAttributedString if all you want is to add some styling to your project.

Comment: Yes I agree is the heavy side and it seems that some people have trouble with. I saw issues about NSAttributedString but not totaly clear what it is?